# Two domains, one app on IIS and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, windows-authentication

This is a scenario :
- two domains DA and DB
- one IIS 7.0 in DA with MVC App, which has Windows Authentication.

My goal is to configure DB or maybe DA too, to let users from DB to use Windows Authentication on MVC App too. BUT I don't want to give them access to DA resources (for example shared folders, files etc).

thanks for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem allmost solved.

I've set mirror MVC App on IIS installed in domain DB. This app works on main database in domain DA. It was easier to do, for me :)